# How to differentiate this matrix multiplication?

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, differential

(Sorry for poor question I don't know how to write a math equation)

$U_i$ for $i=1,2,...,d$ and $M, S$ are $C^{(N \times N)}$ matrices.
And $\alpha_i$ for $i=1,2,...,d$ and $t$ are complex scalars.
$H=\sum_{i=1}^d\alpha_iU_i$ and $Q=\exp(jtH)$ where $j$ is the imaginary unit - $j^2=-1$.

Let $f(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_d)=\operatorname{tr}[MQSQ^H]$

Where $^H$ is the Hermitian transpose.

Then how can we describe the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $\alpha_i$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or your thoughts so far?

Comment: j is standard complex not between (0,1). (i.e. j^2=-1) Thank you for your edit

Comment: Seems tough. Even just the derivative of $Q$ seems like it's going to be unpleasant, unless you have some extra information about the $U_i$ (i.e., they share eigenvectors).

Comment: U_i are just arbitrary NxN complex matrix. Is it impossible to make derivative simply if U_i does not share some properties like eigenvector?

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\b{\beta}
\def\g{{\large g}}
\def\U{{\mho}}
\def\Z{Z^{-1}}
\def\ZT{Z^{-T}}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$For this problem we will employ $\mathbb{CR}$-Calculus (aka Wirtinger differentiation), wherein $\LR{a,a^*}$ are treated as *formally* independent variables.

The extremely useful Frobenius product (denoted by a colon) has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A^*\!:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
\LR{F\odot G}:H &= F:\LR{G\odot H} \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ is the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Let's replace the $U_i$ matrices by defining
a third-order tensor $\,\U\,$ such that
$$\eqalign{
\U &= \sum_k U_k\star e_k \qiq U_k = \U\cdot e_k \\
H &= \U\cdot a = \sum_k\LR{U_k\star e_k}\cdot a = \sum_k {U_k\,\a_k} \\
dH &= \U\cdot da \qiq dH^* = \U^*\cdot da^* \\
}$$
where $(\star)$ denotes the dyadic/tensor product, $a$ is the vector with components $\a_k$ and $\:e_k\in{\mathbb R}^n\,$ are the standard (orthonormal) basis vectors.

The symbol $(\cdot)$ is the single dot product, which is the ordinary matrix product but it is normally suppressed in standard *Matrix Notation*. However, when dealing with tensors it's better to use an explicit product symbol.

Assuming that $H$ is not [defective](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix) (a reasonable assumption), the $\sf Daleckii$ - $\sf Krein$ theorem says
$$\eqalign{
Q &= f(H) \\
H &= ZB\Z, \quad B = \Diag{\b_k} \qquad \big\{{\rm EVD\;of\;}H\big\} \\
\Z\,dQ\:Z &= R\odot\LR{\Z\,dH\:Z} \\
dQ &= Z\BR{R\odot\LR{\Z\,dH\:Z}}\Z \\
\\
R_{jk} &= \begin{cases}
{\large\frac{f(\b_j)\,-\,f(\b_k)}{\b_j\,-\,\b_k}}
  \qquad{\rm if}\;\b_j\ne\b_k \\
\\
  \quad{\small f'(\b_k)}\qquad\qquad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
}$$
The current problem specifies the following function
$$ f(x) = e^{itx} \qquad f'(x) = it\,e^{itx} $$

---

Write the objective function using the above notation.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= I:MQSQ^H \\
d\phi
 &= I:M\,dQ\,SQ^H \;+\; I:MQS\,dQ^H \\
 &= M^TQ^*S^T:dQ \;+\; MQS:dQ^* \\
 &= M^TQ^*S^T:\LR{Z\BR{R\odot\LR{\Z\,dH\:Z}}\Z} \;+\; conj \\
 &= Z\BR{R\odot\LR{Z^TM^TQ^*S^T\ZT}}\Z:\LR{\U\cdot da} \;+\; conj \\
 &= G:\LR{\U\cdot da} \;+\; conj \\
\grad{\phi}{a} &= G:\U \;\doteq\; \g \\
}$$

---

The double-dot product in the last expression can be written explicitly as
$$\eqalign{
\g_k &= \sum_i \sum_j\:G_{ij}\,\U_{ijk}  \\
}$$